# can quaternions be expressed in terms of tensor products?

Tags: tensor-products, quaternions

QUESTIONS

1. does this arithmetic check out?
2. if so, is there a geometric interpretation?

*note:  my aim was to try to find a very simple but non-trivial example which might help me begin to understand tensor products. i apologize if this little exercise is nonsense - or if the question is a duplicate of one already dealt with. my arithmetic is unfortunately always rather error-prone. at first it seemed to work, then, after trying to tidy up the notation, it didn't and i thought i was barking up a non-existent tree.  but finding the scraps of paper a couple of days later, after checking again it looked OK. so rather than flounder around any further i would appreciate input from someone with a more mature understanding.*

for $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ if $v \to vB$ is a reflection in the $x$-axis, and $v \to vC$ is a reflection in the line $x=y$ then the product $v \to vBC = vA$ is a counter-clockwise rotation by $\frac{\pi}2$. these transformations may be represented as matrices:

$$  A =  \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 \\
        -1 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix} \\ $$
$$ B =  \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} \\  $$

$$ C =  \begin{pmatrix}
         0 & 1 \\
         1 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix} \\ $$

with these definitions, and using $I$ to signify the identity matrix, we have the multiplication table:

$$ A^2 = -I, B^2 = I, C^2 =  I \\
AB =  -C  \\
BC =  A  \\
CA =  -B \\
$$
using the tensor (kronecker?) product over $\mathbb{R}$ if we now set:
$$
\mathbf{1}=I \otimes I \\
i = I \otimes A \\
j = A \otimes B \\
k = -A \otimes C  \\
\\
$$
then assuming that with all matrices $2 \times 2$ we have $(P \otimes Q)(R \otimes S) = PR \otimes QS$
$$
i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = -\mathbf{1} \\
ij = k = -ji, \\ jk = i = -kj,\\ ki = j = - ik, \\
$$

Comment: Without checking your calculations, I just want to point out that your tensor products are in ${\rm M}_2(\mathbf R) \otimes_{\mathbf R} {\rm M}_2(\mathbf R)$, which is isomorphic to ${\rm M}_4({\mathbf R})$. It is well-known that the quaternions can be realized inside ${\rm M}_4(\mathbf R)$; see the section about matrix representations on the Wikipedia page for quaternions. Therefore it would not be surprising that you can find a realization of the quaternions $i$, $j$, and $k$ inside ${\rm M}_2(\mathbf R) \otimes_{\mathbf R} {\rm M}_2(\mathbf R)$.

Comment: thank you KCd, i will check out the reference

Comment: Comparing the representation of quaternions as $4 \times 4$ real matrices in the Wikipedia page on quaternions with the formula for Kronecker products (that is the  concrete matrix expression of tensor products of matrices -- see the Wikipedia page on Kronecker products), the connection with your notation $A$, $B$, and $C$ is that $1 = I \otimes I$, $i = B \otimes A$, $j = A \otimes I$, and $k = C \otimes A$.

Comment: @KCd this looks like a very useful subject for me to investigate, leading in several directions i have heard of but never really come to grips with. i've just seen, for example (in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Rodrigues_parameters#Connection_with_quaternions) that what i have termed I, A. B, C     are closely related to what are called the "Pauli spin matrices" - which would be I, A, iB and iC (with i=$\sqrt{-1}$ ) which gives me a handle on the still (to me) rather mysterious notion of Lie Groups, here the Lie group SU(2). it will take some time to absorb this info!

Comment: Of which quaternions do we speak, of W.R. Hamilton’s (where *i²* = *j²* = *k²* = **−1**), or ?

Comment: Ah, got this over-complicated stuff, at last ☺

Comment: Can the complex numbers, represented as 2-by-2 matrices, be treated as a tensor construction as well?